# Redis how to match roundtrip request response

Tags: redis

I have a http server application that receives requests from HTTP clients and puts them to a Redis List for processing.  Another process listening on this list picks up the requests and processes them, and finally puts the response into another Redis Queue to be consumed by the HTTP server.

The sequence is like this:

(1)  Http Client ==>    Web app 
(2)  Web App     ==>    Redis Request Queue (List data structure) 
(3)  Processor   ==>    consumes requests using multiple threads and processes them
(4)  Processor   ==>    puts to a Redis Response Queue (List data structure) 
(5)  Web App     ==>    has to pick the response from the response que and deliver to HTTP clients

Given the above scenario, if multiple threads on the HTTP server are queueing the msgs to Redis, is there any established pattern to ensure responses are correctly picked up and sent back to HTTP clients using the right session?

I am planning to use Redis (or may be RabbitMQ or ZeroMQ) for the producer/consumer, because I want to scale horizontally and configure many consumers spread across several nodes.

Thanks for pointing me a reasonable approach on this.

Comment: Does web app wait for the processor to produce result? If so, this doesn't look very scalable to me.

Comment: How are you passing the client socket to the processors?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I agree. But since its a HTTP client, I believe it will have to wait for processor to produce a result. Is there a better way,

Comment: @TheRealBill Passing a HTTP socket cud b an option. I am still in design thinking phase. 

If I create a servlet which can run on multiple threads (tomcat worker threads), there is no way these threads can trace back the response from processor. Or is it?

Comment: Or should I consider using *web sockets* for *pushing* the message back to HTTP clients, when responses are ready? Each response can be identified by a "txn_id"?  Is there any other way?

Comment: You'll need to look into how HTTP works better before continuing this path. The browser connects to the server and expects a response back on the socket it opened. Unless you have that socket (fd) you can't talk back to the browser. Otherwise you would need to go with a "call back (other URL) later with this job Id and I'll get you the results" route.